# Generators of the product group $G \times H$ given two finite groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Was wondering about the generators of $G\times H$ given two finite groups $G, H$ and supposing you knew their generators (abstractly).  In particular $G, H$ are both $p$-groups for different $p$.

Does $S \times T$ generate $G \times H$ whenever $S$ generates $G$ and $T$ generates $H$?

Comment: Not necessarily. If $G$ and $H$ are both cyclic, then you can take $S$ and $T$ singletons, in which case $S\times T$ is a singleton. But then for $S\times T$ to generate $G\times H$ it would be necessary that $G\times H$ be cyclic, and the product of two cyclic groups is cyclic if and only if their orders are coprime. So that lets you generate lots and lots of counterexamples to $S\times T$ generating $G\times H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need all of $S\times T$; Since the two components of $G\times H$ don't "speak" with each other (meaning, the product is determined individually for each component), you can simply use the sets ${(g_i,e_h)}, {(e_g,h_i)}$ where $h_i\in T, g_i\in S$.

Take some member of $G \times H - (a,b)$. We know that each component can be expressed as the product of generators of its respective group - $(a,b)=(g_1g_2...g_n,h_1h_2...h_k)$. This means that: $$(a,b)=(g_1,e_h)...(g_n,e_h)(e_g,h_1)...(e_g,h_k)$$

And so each element may be expressed as a product of elements from our given set. As an exercise, show that the given set cannot be reduced - if we take away any generator from the set, then there will be some element in $G\times H$ which will not be generated by our set.

Comment: That makes sense.  Except, can't you take away a member if $T, S$ were not minimal?  Also your first hyphenation appears that you're removing $(a,b)$ from the group.

Comment: What if $S$ and $T$ don't contain the identity elements, though?  Indeed, in general $S\times T$ may not generate $G\times H$ if $S$ generates $G$ and $T$ generates $H$ (consider when $G$ and $H$ are cyclic of the same order and $S$ and $T$ are singletons, for instance).  In the particular case of the question where $G$ and $H$ are $p$-groups for different primes you can show this can't happen but it takes a bit of work.

Comment: You're correct, I assumed you meant T and S to be minimal. If they are not, you are able to take out elements.

Comment: S and T don't have to contain the identity element - we choose a set of the form described above and get it for free - the identity of each group is also a product of the elements of T or S respectively, and so we can generate it using the generating set described above, am I wrong? The set contains the identity in each component, without assuming it belings to S or T

Comment: You're right that the set you described generates $G\times H$, but it doesn't answer OP's question of whether $S\times T$ generates $G\times H$.

Comment: I now see that I misunderstood what OP was asking - thanks.